# Validation of text objects or handling on objects that dont appear in all cases in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have to validate a page text after logging into an application,
Text/ that page dont appear everytime but if the page appears then I have to do some actions and if it dont appear then I have to proceed.

I tried the below methods :
1.

```
Run Keyword If    Page Should Contain   ${txt_HomePage}  Login Successful
     Else    Login Unsuccessful
   
Login Successful
     Log     Successfully logged into application
     
Login Unsucessful
     Log     Please verify userid and password
```

2. 

```
${Result}=   Page Should Contain    ${txt_HomePage} 
Run Keyword Unless  '${RESULT}'=='PASS'    Log   Unsucessfull
```

Both the cases are failing, any other suggestion? How to handles that objects that dont appear in all cases

Comment: Show the page html and what text is being displayed so that people can debug your problem, need not to share sensitive information

Comment: Its just a page text - For eg: Login Page in a text format.
My issue is it wont reach to that page sometimes. My test cases has a buffer of 30mins that some pages can be active and no need to go through that extra level of verification. So I need to validate whether that page text exist then do the process no, then do the other set of process. Here, it fails saying that "Page should contain but it doesn't have that text". Hope I am making some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robot Framework is not very elegant when need to test a system that does not always behave same way. You can use RF `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` to get pass/fail and work on that:

```
${status}   ${message}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain   ${txt_HomePage}
IF          "${status}" == "PASS"
            Log     Successfully logged into application
ELSE
            Log     Please verify userid and password
END
```